Supabase - Issue with redirect in Next.js v14.2.12 Not Working for Logged-in Users
Issue with encodedRedirect in Next.js v14.2.12 Not Working for Logged-in Users (Using Supabase)
I’m facing an issue with encodedRedirect in my Next.js (v14.2.12) project, which uses Supabase for authentication. The function works perfectly for non-logged-in users, but it doesn’t trigger the redirection when the user is logged in. Instead, the URL remains unchanged, and no redirect occurs. Here’s the breakdown:
Example Scenario (Working for Non-Logged-in Users):
When a non-logged-in user performs an action like signing up, the encodedRedirect function works as expected, redirecting them to:
https://www.*******.com/signup?success=Thanks%20for%20signing%20up%21%20Please%20check%20your%20email%20for%20a%20verification%20link

The message is then displayed using a formMessage component.
The Problem:
However, when a logged-in user tries to do the same action (e.g., sign up), the redirection doesn’t happen. The URL stays the same (e.g., https://www.**********.com/signup), and the encoded message isn’t passed through or displayed.
Here’s my encodedRedirect function:
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

/**
 * Redirects to a specified path with an encoded message as a query parameter.
 * @param {('error' | 'success')} type - The type of message, either 'error' or 'success'.
 * @param {string} path - The path to redirect to.
 * @param {string} message - The message to be encoded and added as a query parameter.
 * @returns {never} This function doesn't return as it triggers a redirect.
 */
export function encodedRedirect(
  type: "error" | "success",
  path: string,
  message: string,
) {
  return redirect(`${path}?${type}=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`);
}

Example of the issue:
return encodedRedirect(
  "error",
  "/dashboard",
  "Could not verify session. Please log in again."
);

In this case, the redirect works fine for non-logged-in users but does nothing for logged-in users.
Version Info:

Next.js: 14.2.12
Supabase for authentication

What I’ve Tried:

Tried using older versions of Next.js to see if the issue persists.
Ran depcheck to check for unused or missing dependencies, but everything looks fine.
Disabled middleware to check if it’s affecting the redirect, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
Logged the redirect URL in both logged-in and logged-out states—it’s correct in both cases.


You should share what the code inside of the signup endpoint looks like.
